# Chrome extension pass current tab url over chrome.runtime.onMessage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build web annotation reader extension for chrome. My problem is I cannot get active tab url inside background script (btw, I don't know if this is the correct term). Let me show you the code. This is from "highlight.js" file

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msgObj => {
  if (msgObj.action == "getData") {
    var annotations = msgObj.annotations;

    // Messaging 2
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getURL" }, (response) => {
      alert(response.data)
    });

    // I want to have current tab url here...
  }

  // ...

});
```

And my "eventPage.js" is

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  // Messaging 1
  // ...

  // Messaging 2
  if (request.action === "getURL") {

    chrome.tabs.query({ 'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true }, function (tabs) {
      // I want url_ to be transferred to highlight.js but no luck so far...
      const url_ = tabs[0].url;
      sendResponse({ data: url_ });
      return true;
    });
  }
});
```

And my manifest file is:

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"Annotation Reader",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description":"An annotation reader extension!",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16":"icon16.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon128.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
      "eventPage.js"
    ],
    "persistent":false
  },  
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
    //...
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": 
      [
        // ...
      ],
      "js": [
        "jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
        "jquery.highlight.js",
        "highlight.js"
      ],
      "css": ["highlight.css"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's no need for messaging, simply use `location.href` in the content script. Each matching tab/frame runs its own instance of the content script so things like DOM `document` or `window` or `location` belong to the tab/frame.
2. Although you don't need it here, but when `sendResponse` is used asynchronously (callbacks in `chrome` extension API are always called asynchronously), the messaging port needs to be kept open by returning `true` from the onMessage listener, not from the nested callback.

   ```
   if (something) {
     asyncCall(params, result => {
       sendResponse(result);
     });
     return true;
   }
   ```
3. Content scripts are running in all matching tabs/frames, not just the active tab, so messages can come from an inactive tab. It means that chrome.tabs.query is the wrong approach. The correct solution is to use `sender.url` directly if the URL is needed. Use the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage) to learn about the parameters so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.